# How to click this Logout Icon using Selenium Webdriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a banking portal which have Div structure for logout in below given

```
<div class ="bar bar-desktop small-12 columns">
 <a id="j_idt39:logoutMenu" terminatevbsess="" href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon-logout" ng-click="click($event,{s:&quot;j_idt39:logoutMenu&quot;,p:&quot;menUid&quot;,u:&quot;menUid&quot;});">
  ::before
  <i class="icon left "></i>
 </a>
</div>
```

When I identify Logout Icon `:: before` is being highlighted. Please let me know how I can identify and how to select locator for this icon.

Comment: Please recheck the html you have added. have a look at the id of the link attribute. Why dont you just select the link instead of looking for the icon?

Comment: Try finding the element with classname or xpath or id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cssSelector to find the logout icon. try using `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon-logout")).click()`

Comment: I tried that earlier but it is failing and am seeing error unable to locate element.

Answer (score 0):

Get xpath using Firepath and click on Logout button that is **a** tag.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).click();

In your html code you cannot find **id** easily because some problem in html code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinkText:

driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("::before")).click();

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.icon-logout > i");
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: I will try and let you know if there are any questions. thanks!

Comment: please give a thumbs and answered  !!